# Trailing space added during insert in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oledbconnection

I am facing issue while inserting a record in oracle 10g. I am running a parameterised query from asp.net using oledb [with dbhelper class]. The values of fields which are passed as parameter in query, after execution have extra space at end in the Database. The datatype of fields are varchar2. This issue only occurs when the connection is made using Oracle provider for oledb. When i use microsoft provider for oracle then no extra space is inserted at the end.

The oracle database is 64 bit.
Client used to access the DB is of version 11.2.....

Is this a known issue or i am missing some thing.

Suggest something as i am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, two ideas come to mind.  Change the INSERT statement to truncate its input, as in:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)
  VALUES (TRUNC(@param1), TRUNC(@param2), TRUNC(@param3))
```

Second option: write a stored procedure which accepts the parameters as inputs and truncates them in the INSERT statement, as in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_INTO_TABLE(pParam1  IN  VARCHAR2,
                                              pParam2  IN  VARCHAR2,
                                              pParam3  IN  VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE(FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)
    VALUES (TRUNC(pParam1), TRUNC(pParam2), TRUNC(pParam3));
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;  -- do something appropriate here
END INSERT_INTO_TABLE;
```

Comment: or a pre insert trigger that trims the value before insert

Comment: This is fine.. We can truncate the input.. But i am not getting reason, why space got added.. Even there is nothing like that in value of parameter..

Answer (score 0):

If working with C#, use `Trim()` while passing parameters to the query/stored proc to remove both leading and trailing white-spaces.
Eg:

```
param1= TextBox1.Text.Trim();
```